# Гости пользователя

Tags: php

Возможно ли реализовать функцию гостей пользователя?
То есть список пользователей, посетивших чью-либо страницу.
Каков примерный алгоритм?

Answer (score 4):

Таблица гости:

```
guests {
  id - autoincrement
  user
  visiter
  time
}
```

При заходе на страницу:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO guests (user, visiter, time) VALUES ('.$pageID.', '.$myID.', '.time().')');
```

Выборка посетителей за сутки:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM guests JOIN users ON (guests.visitor=users.id) WHERE guests.user='.$myID.' AND guests.time>='.(time()-3600*24).' ORDER BY guests.id DESC');
```

Этого должно хватить.

Answer (score 2):

Создать в БД таблицу `profile_guests` с полями:

```
id,
profile_id,
guest_id,
guest_name, //лишнее
guest_photo, //лишнее
time_visit
```

Если к пользователю пришел гость, создаем запрос по его id. Узнаем есть ли запись в базе у этого профиля с id такого гостя, если нету создаем новую запись, если есть обновляем время визита. Соответственно сортируем по `time_visit` что-бы обладатель профиля знал кто и во сколько к ниму приходил!

Тут по большому щету нужна верная постановка запросов к БД для чтения, записи, обновления данных. Ну и соответственно верно спроектирована таблица в БД!

Ну и еще одна важная вещь - **ЛОГИКА**!

**UPD**: Хотя с `guest_name` и `guest_photo` я погорячился) Тут JOIN'ами выруливать нужно! [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) +1

Answer (score 0):

Есть пользователь, у него есть id.

Есть таблица посещений, в которой есть данные: id пользователя и id посетителя(можно  еще дату)

Можно запросом получить список посетителей любого пользователя.